# Intel MKL function cblas_sgemv gives different results each time

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, intel-mkl

I used Intel MKL's function cblas_sgemv to do matrix-vector multiplication but this function gives different results each time. Sometimes this can give the correct result (with 1e-6 error in L2 norm compared with the reference result).

I have checked that the inputs of this function are the same each time and I just use this function according to [this document](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-cblas-gemv).

My code is as follows:

```
cblas_sgemv(CblasRowMajor, Trans, M, N, alpha, A, lda, x, incx, beta, y, incy);
```

Hope someone can shed some light.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem. The solution can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/657060).

Comment: link no longer valid